# JavaScript output

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and instead of

> 918273645546372819099

output in HTML, I want to see something like:

> 9
>
> 18
>
> 27 etc.

```
// Creating a while loop
    var myValue = 9;

    // Loop to find numbers that are multiples of nine that are less than 100
    while (myValue < 100)
    {
        if (myValue % 9 == 0)
        {
            document.write(myValue);
        }

        myValue++;
    }
```

Comment: Just fyi on the use of document.write http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: just add line breaks? see my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line break or two. Furthermore, you can move the increment operator in the condition check for the while loop.

```
var myValue = 9;

// Loop to find numbers that are multiples of nine that are less than 100
while (myValue++ < 100)
{
    if (myValue % 9 === 0)
    {
        document.write(myValue + '<br/><br/>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add operators with side effects into a condition. It makes it harder to read and debug. It's an item checked by almost all JS linters.

Comment: I can see why this could be a problem in general.

Comment: That means it's is possible to add html snippets in the javascript code?